# Kafka enable.auto.commit set to false but poll still fetch "next" messages

Tags: apache-kafka, message-hub

I want to tell Kafka when my consumer has successfully processed a record so I have turned auto-commit off by settting `enable.auto.commit` to false.  I have two messages on a topic I am subscribed to at offset zero and one and have created a consumer so that each call to `poll` will return at most *one* record (by setting `max.poll.records` to 1).

I now call `consumer.poll(5000)` and receive the first message but I do not acknowledge it; I do not call `commitSync` or `commitAsync`.  If I now call `consumer.poll(5000)` again, using the same consumer, I expect to get the exact same message I just read but, instead, I receive the second message.

How do I get `consumer.poll` to keep handing out the same message until I explicitly acknowledge it?

Comment: P.S.  I am using IBM Message Hub (which uses Kafka underneath the covers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you described is the expected behaviour. Every time you call `poll()`, it will return the next messages. The offset you commit is only used when connecting a new consumer so it knows where to (re)start from.

In MessageHub, we've set the `session.timeout` to 30 seconds. So you need to call `poll()` slightly faster to avoid being disconnected. If your processing takes longer than that, then I can think of 2 options:

- Use Kafka 0.10.2 and set `max.poll.interval.ms` to tell your Kafka client to keep the session alive (without you having to call `poll()`) while you process the previous record. (This feature was added in 0.10.1 but we don't support that version. 0.10.2 works because it's capable to work with 0.10.0 brokers)
- Use seek() to move back to the previous offset after `poll` so it keeps returning the same record.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the advantage of using kafka.Consume() method thats available now, instead of Poll()? would that also behave the same way of bringing the next message whlie the first message has been deleted/removed even though i didnt mark it as commited?

Comment: Not sure which API you're referring to but there's no `Consume()` method in the official client: https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: I was referring to the Confluent.Kafka package for .net/c#.